# Select rows with a value on a field and between two values on another

Tags: sql-server, select

I can't get to work a SELECT and beg for help :)

I need to select rows with one ID on a field and Two specified values on another, for example:

```
ID.......COLOR........SIZE
001......GREEN........M
001......GREEN........L
001......GREEN........XL
001......GREEN........2XL
001......GREEN........3XL
001......RED..........2XL
002......WHITE........XL
002......WHITE........2XL
002......WHITE........3XL
```

Then I would like to get each ID & COLOR which have both two values in SIZE (2XL AND 3XL for example) like this:

```
001......GREEN......2XL
001......GREEN......3XL
002......WHITE......2XL
003......WHITE......3XL
```

"001-RED-2XL" should not be included as there's no "3XL" on same ID and COLOR row.

Many thanks in advance!

Sweet greets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved with two correlated subqueries used as `EXISTS` filter conditions.

```
SELECT t.id, t.color, t.size
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    t.size IN ('2XL', '3XL')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = t.id AND color = t.color AND size = '2XL')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = t.id AND color = t.color AND size = '3XL')
```

Another solution is to use a self-join :

```
SELECT t.id, t.color, t.size
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN mytable t2 
    ON t2.id = t.id
    AND t2.color = t.color
    AND (
         ( t.size = '2XL' AND t2.size = '3XL' )
         OR ( t.size = '3XL' AND t2.size = '2XL' )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB, both options works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists this way:

```
select t.* from tablename t where
exists (
  select 1 from tablename where
  id = t.id and color = t.color and 
  size in ('2XL', '3XL') and t.size in ('2XL', '3XL') and
  size <> t.size
)
order by t.id, t.color, t.size
```